# Reading excel file failing due to lock with null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am newbie to java & programming. I have a bunch of code which reads data from excel and uses it for running some test cases(selenium webdriver).
Below code shows reading data from excel which works fine when running my test cases serially(one by one).

```
public String getData(String SheetName, String DataSet, String ColumnName) throws                JXLException,IOException {         
        Workbook workbook=null;            
        workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(".\\data\\TestData.xls"));
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(SheetName); 
        int iRow,iCol=0,iNumCol,p;
        String sData="";      
        Cell sTestData=sheet.findCell(DataSet);
        iNumCol=sheet.getColumns();
        iRow=sTestData.getRow();
        for (p=0;p<iNumCol;p++)
        {               
            String sCol=sheet.getCell(p,0).getContents();
            if (sCol.matches(ColumnName))
            {
                iCol=p;
                bColumnFound=true;
            }   

          }      
        sData = sheet.getCell(iCol,iRow).getContents();    
        return sData;  
    }
```

```
@Test(testName = "list_News")
@Parameters("format")
public void list_News(String format) throws Exception {

String sgetname = "", sPassword = "", sUrl = ""; 
sgetname = cm.getData("list_News", "list_News", "idname");  >>> THIS STEP I am getting NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
sPassword = cm.getData("list_News", "list_News", "Password");
sUrl = cm.getData("list_News", "list_News", "URL");
```

My Question is - when i try to run multiple cases concurrently, I am getting Null Pointer exception as shown below.
The point where its failing at every case is at the first line of reading excel file. I suspect it might be some lock caused during reading excel file.
How Do I resolve this issue....is it multiThreading that i need to implement and how Do i do that?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at common.commonMethods.getData(commonMethods.java:241)
at api.case.list.Listnews.test_paperid_Pos_014(news_uth.java:282)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks In Advance
    Cheers

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException` at `commonMethods.java:241`.  Because we don't have line numbers in your sample, can you post what line 241 is?

Comment: Line number 241 has this code
sgetname = pm.getData("list_news", "list_news_testcase1", "idname"); 
pm.getData is the reading excel method i have posted above..

Comment: Is the method you posted, `getData`, the one where the exception is happening?  I don't see that line in the code sample you posted.  Need to see the full code to better understand what is going on just before the `NPE`.

Comment: I have mentioned the code above  Please look for this line.  >>> THIS STEP I am getting NULL POINTER EXCEPTION at that point

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forgetting to test if you found value. Try that:

```
public String getData(String SheetName, String DataSet, String ColumnName) throws JXLException, IOException {
    Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File( ".\\data\\TestData.xls"));
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(SheetName);
    Cell sTestData = sheet.findCell(DataSet);
    int iNumCol = sheet.getColumns();
    int iRow = sTestData.getRow();
    boolean bColumnFound = false;
    int iCol;

    for (int p = 0; p < iNumCol; p++) {
        String sCol = sheet.getCell(p, 0).getContents();
        if (sCol.matches(ColumnName)) {
            iCol = p;
            bColumnFound = true;
        }

    }
    if (!bColumnFound) {
        return "";
    }
    return sheet.getCell(iCol, iRow).getContents();
}
```

I don't know what API you are using, so i can't test.

Comment: I am using jxl.........
    import jxl.Workbook;
    import jxl.Cell;
    import jxl.JXLException;
    import jxl.Sheet

Comment: I also would like to update you that I am able to read the excel file successfully when i run a test case one by one. When i am trying to run test cases concurrently, i see this NPE.

Comment: I think the library is making a file lock when are reading the file. I don't know how your library works, so i can't help you more.